# DatePicker not getting disabled on change in state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please see the following code. I have a dropdown with 3 values, the DatePicker should conditionally get disabled when the user chooses 1, or 2 from the dropdown. But this is not happening.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export default function DateRangePicker() {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
    const [rangeType, setRangeType] = useState(1);

    return <div>
        <select value={rangeType} onChange={e => setRangeType(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="1">This Month</option>
            <option value="2">This Year</option>
            <option value="3">Date Range</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <ReactDatePicker
            disabled={rangeType !== 3}
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={e => setStartDate(e)}
        />
    </div>;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: can you do a console.log of rangeType when you select a value?

Comment: Yes its changing and showing the updated value when the user selects a different value in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print a console log on the onChange, but from what I'm reading I suppose that the problem is the type: you're comparing string and numbers.